# Advanced Orchard Theming - Object Model vs Placement.info?

Tags: orchardcms, theming

I have been tasked with converting a design heavy, fairly advanced HTML template for a site into an Orchard theme and I am struggling with the best way to accomplish certain things.  The theme is built on bootstrap and is a modern responsive HTML template like you might find on ThemeForest or something.  The site will have a number of content types (staff members, portfolio items, partners, etc.) and will need a number of templates.  The content types will have a large number of fields (upwards of a dozen) inside of custom content parts.

Based on what I have read the proper way to do theming in Orchard is using placement.info in combination with alternates, wrappers, etc. This gracefully handles if parts or properties are added/removed. However, this technique is quickly becoming overwhelming, since I have to declare the name and order of every field/part in the placement.info for every content type, and every display type of that content type.  Each field of each content type then needs to be wrapped in very specific html.  This creates an issue because a single page can be split out into potentially a couple dozen views, with HTML tags opening in one view and closing in another.

The best work around for this I have found is to basically ignore the placement.info file and build templates just by traversing the object model.  So basically, for a portfolio page, I would copy in the template HTML I have and then replace the text values with values from the model.  This might look something like:

```
<li class="@Display(Model.ContentItem.PortfolioPart.PortfolioCore.Value.ToLower())">

    <a href="@Url.ItemDisplayUrl(contentItem)" >


        @foreach (var media in Model.ContentItem.PortfolioPart.PortfolioImage.MediaParts)
          {
                <img src="@Display(media.MediaUrl)" />
            }
                    <span class="type">@Display(Model.ContentItem.PortfolioPart.PortfolioCoreArea.Value)</span>
                    <span class="portfolio-item-content">
                        <span class="header">@Display(Model.ContentItem.TitlePart.Title)</span>
                        <span class="body">
                            <p>
                                @Display(Model.ContentItem.PortfolioPart.PortfolioTagline.Value)
                            </p>
                        </span>
                    </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

The benefit with this method is that I can apply all of the values in a couple of views and it's more readable.  Obviously the problem with this is that if any properties or parts are removed, the template breaks.

Is there a way in Orchard to have the best of both worlds?  I can't have a wrapper or template for every field - this would end up potentially hundreds of fields by the end.  I also might need to display content types in multiple places with different views - each field would then require a whole new set of wrappers or alternates for every projection.

Please let me know if I'm missing anything or if there is a better way to do this besides manually traversing to the properties I need.  I need a way to be able to easily plug in properties into very specific html.

My final thought was to use very specific templates for custom content types using the object model but still provide good general templates/placement.info file so that general Orchard content is flexible but the custom content types have to stay how they are.

Side thought - I guess another option would be to wrap any code that accesses a property directly in a try catch block or some kind of error handler helper, but that doesn't seem like a "best practice".

Answer (score 0):

I think the techniques in this article are what you're looking for: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2013/02/13/easy-content-templates-for-orchard-take-2.aspx

Comment: Hi Bertrand,
Thanks for the response! That article is helpful but can you elaborate on what the advantage is of injecting a content part into a zone instead of just accessing the Content Part/Properties directly from the model? Is it because since you are using Placement.Info it won't break if someone removes that part? If inside the zone Orchard uses the Content Part template to access properties of the part directly, will that still break if the content manager removes properties?  I hope these questions make sense, appreciate your time.

Comment: You can access the properties directly if you prefer, the article actually does that as well. The article makes a point that the technique gives you the best of both.